# Plug in doesn't work in IE 11 on Win7 64bit

Tags: internet-explorer, lastpass

I have three browsers, Chrome, Firefox and IE11.  Last pass works as expected on Chrome and FF but not on IE 11.  It is as if it isn't even installed.  I have re-installed Lastpass several time, always checked that it is enabled in IE 11 but nothing.  Whenever I visit a site that requires a login I need to switch browsers or open the the Vault on a tab so I can see the credentials I need to log in.

Am I the only person with the experience?

Comment: Lastpass support can help you.  Lastpass works without any problems on IE11.

Comment: I posted on their support site w/o any help and had another user post that they are having the same problem.

Comment: You created a support ticket and recieved no response to your ticket?  I find that unlikely.

Comment: I'm glad you replied, I thought posting on the user forum was the process to get help with my issue, I in fact did not create a ticket I only posted on the forum without any help from any of the moderators or other forum members.  I'll see about opening a ticket

Comment: So far LastPass support has proved less than useless. In my initial support ticket I provided specific information. 4 communications later the rep asks for the identical information.  Each time a single piece from the original ticket. I swear the original ticket must not be read.  Does anyone have any suggestions to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I use ie 11 and lastpass it's my only extension in ie infact and it works flawlessly I have no suggestions except going through support

Comment: My OS is WIN7 64bit, which OS are you using?

Comment: IE11 is IE11 I am not sure if that matters.  Since you asked I loaded a Windows 7 x64 virtual machine, installed IE11 and lastpass and tested it, as I expect I had no problems.

Comment: OK, thanks for checking this out; this is really odd.  Seems to me that if I had something external affecting Lastpass plugin for IE that it would equally affect FF and Chrome but they work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Internet Explorer: make sure that third party extensions are allowed by going to the Internet Explorer Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > 'Enable Third-Party Browser Extensions'. Check Tools > Manage Add-Ons to make sure LastPass is enabled there.

https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=385

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to sound odd, However, go into your control panel. Open up your programs and features. → select uninstall program → and just see if IE is actually installed.

If IE isn't installed as True. then go to.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx
to download: Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 7 64bit.

If none of these work. Try looking into whitelisting the application via Regeit.